# Stopping the iteration of all the elements of a vector at convergence in matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration, convergence

I want to iterate all of the elements in my matrix and want them to stop when the value converges of all the elements. I wrote the code (below) but its giving me wrong values and i dont think if values are actually going in the loop.

```
probability = (ones(1,2048) .* 1/2048); %vector of 2048 values
Tij = sum(StateTransitionfwd); %vector of 2048 values
Tji = sum(StateTransitionbwd); %vector of 2048 values
p = ((Tji .* probability) - (Tij .* probability)); %vector of 2048 values

threshold = (zeros(1,2048)); %vector of 2048 values
old = p; %vector of 2048 values
new = zeros(1,2048); %vector of 2048 values

while old - new > threshold %subtracting vector from the vector    
   old = p;     
   p = ((p * StateTransitionbwd) - (Tij .* p));     
   new = p;        
end
```

Comment: I think your array will simply never converge to zero and therefore always run. Try setting the threshold higher or include a maximum number of iterations in your while-loop condition.

Comment: @Visser I tried doing it. values were not going into the loop first but by using  norm(old - new) they are. But now I am getting values in Inf or NaN :s

Comment: Both Tij and Tji are scalars. Multiplying them with probability gives an array containing 2048 values which are exactly the same. Subtracting those two arrays again gives a 2048 element array with exactly the same entries. Only when you assign p inside the while loop things start to change, providing StateTransitionbwd is a 2048 array of distinct values.

Comment: The number of elements remain the same (that is 2048) but their values are in NaN or inf.

Answer (score 0):

You stopping condition `old - new > threshold` is problematic, since it is not evaluated into a **scalar** boolean value, but to a **vector** of boolean values.
You should instead measure the *norm* of the difference vector, for example

```
while max( abs( old-new) ) > threshold
```

Or

```
while norm( old-new) > threshold
```

Comment: The loop worked and values are going in the loop atleast. But the output is NaN or negative Infinty :s

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your old vector might be the 0 vector as well. If you get an error of NaN or inf when testing the loop condition it is because you try to find the norm of the zero vector with norm(old-new). The norm of a vector is calculated by v/||v|| so if ||v|| is 0, your vector will be NaN.